# Need Hibernate to access properties through non-standard getters and setters

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a base class for many other classes.
In this base class I have two methods:

```
getProperty(String propName)
```

which returns the property value whose name is passed through propName.

```
setProperty(String propName, Object value)
```

which sets the value of property whose name is passed through propName

I need hibernate to access the properties through these methods for all sub classes.

I didn't find any straight forward way to do this. But I found two classes *PropertyAccess* and *PropertyAccessStrategy* that seems to be the key for what I need.

I couldn't find much documentation about these classes.

Can anyone help me out on how to use these.

Thanks in advance.